# Can't ping from my Amazon EC2 instance running Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, firewall, ping

I have been searching for a while, but it seems like most people have same issue but in the other direction. Meaning that the can't seem to ping their Server.

I am trying to use putty to access my machine from my Server on an Amazon EC2 Instance, and I can't seem to connect. I can't even ping Google from my Server.

Echo ports are open, and I've opened SSH ports. But I still can't even Ping from it.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thank you

EDIT: I tried turning the server firewall off for all profiles, and no luck yet. So it seems to be a windows configuration problem.

Comment: Huh? You're trying to ping your desktop machine from your server?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get a connection out so I'm pinging Google. It resolves the DNS, but hangs on waiting for a response. What I'm trying to do it PuTTY into my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your security groups in your AWS Panel

[image]

Make sure nothing is blocking it there.

Comment: I tried opening every port. Both on the Console and on the server. So apparently that's not the problem.

Thank you though

Comment: So, though I opened all TCP ports, I dd not know that ping was not TCP. I had to open an Echo (Reply) port to be able to use it. Thanks for your help.